# kerascv retinanet for gender identification

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras, object-detection

I am using KerasCV Retinanet to detect people and their genders in images.

I  would like to detect "man", "woman", "boy", "girl" and "baby" in images. I treat them as separate classes in my annotation. Should I detect "person" and then use a separate classification model to figure out the gender or is gender identification by using just retinanet is the right approach?

I have been struggling with the implementation; hence, was not sure if the problem is my approach or the data quality.

Thanks,

Doug